# IntelliJ IDEA maven Run/Debug Configuration, maven goal is run but app does not run automatically

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, configuration

I'm very new to IntelliJ. I want to configure maven project with it. What I have done so far to create run/debug config is, from maven projects window by right-click on the `Project Name > Lifecycle > verify` and then `Create 'Project name [verify]'`. So this created the configuration and it actually runs maven verify goal but does not run the app after that.

So output looks something like this:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.696 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-21T15:39:20+04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see everything goes well. After that I can of course run program manually, but how the hell do I run it automatically?

It seems like runner configuration problem, but dunno.

Comment: Maven lifecycles are there just to make your life easier. They will not run the application (they just call proper maven method like you can do it in console). If you have Java Application with main method. Simply right click on main method and hit run. Otherwise search for green arrow usually in top menu.

Comment: why can't you just run explicitly with intellij?

Comment: The main goal of the Maven relates to the build. In general, you don't need to run app with Maven

Comment: @solomkinmv @Milkmaid Thanks for answering, I know what maven is for but then why does intellij have `Runner` tab inside maven config? IMHO that is for running the app after build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a run/debug configuration (type: Application) for your main class, and add your Maven goal in the 'Before launch' options of the configuration. That will first run Maven and subsequently start your program.

Comment: Do you know what `Runner` tab is for inside maven configuration dialog?

Comment: It enables you to specify some run settings, such as -Xms512m -Xmx1024m as VM options to specify the amount of memory. All this will be saved if you save your run configuration.